# Can't stretch VMware guest OS? 4k res on host OS = screwed up resolution in VM

Tags: vmware

I'm basically trying to figure out if there's a way to just "scale" my VMware guest OSes to stretch across my screen, as opposed to also modifying their resolutions by default and having everything tiny in them as well.

Is there an easy way to do this? This is like the last thing I need to figure out. I can easily decrease the resolution within the VM, but then it shrinks the entire window (or adds a black border around the VM) and the text still ends up being tiny. Not saying that it shouldn't be, but just asking if there's a way to get around this in a VM. The "stretch guest" option is also grayed out.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you are having a conflict with that GPU on the host, in so much as the Host OS is not allowing or is not configured to pass the full features of the gpu to the VM, check your display settings for that VM in the VMware manager tool.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Not quite sure though what you mean by the VMware Manager tool. If I go into the VM's settings and go to the "Display" option, the only options that I have are to  disable/enable 3d acceleration (already enabled), change the number of monitors used and resolution (doesn't seem to work regardless of what I've tried), and to change the amount of memory that the guest can use for graphics memory.

Comment: try the resolution ( on a 4k should be anything from 1920x1200 up to 3980x2820 or similiar)

Comment: Not quite sure what you're referring to here. Try the resolution? I've changed the resolution several times on both the VM and the host, and the only thing that fixes this problem is changing DPI settings on the host. However, this affects everything and not just the VM's guest, so this isn't really acceptable.